# Finding $\tan x$ from $24\sin x\cos x-5=14\cos^2(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

$24\sin x\cos x-5=14\cos^2x$

I tried $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$ but nothing.. I know it's something really simple as this is from a physics problem I only need the value of $\tan x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide both sides by $\cos^2{x}$ to get

$24\tan{x} -5\sec^2{x}=14$

Then use $\sec^2{x}=\tan^2{x}+1$ to get

$5\tan^2{x}-24\tan{x}+19=0$

Answer (score 2):

Dividing the given equation by  $\cos^2 x$ we get
\begin{align*}
24\tan x-5\sec^2 x&=14
\end{align*}
Which is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
5\tan^2 x-24\tan x+19&=0\\
(5\tan x-19)(\tan x-1)&=0
\end{align*}
So $$\tan x =\frac{19}5\quad\text{or}\quad\tan x=1$$